# Screen width of mobile devices ( android and ipod both)

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ios, css

I am creating a web-app where I need to truncate overflowing text. Mean I want to display text into some width ( say 90% of original width) and then want to trim my text if it occupies more space. If I need to trim any text then i will put ellipse (...) at the end of the text.

**I have tried below three approaches.But could not get any which could work on all devices.**

1- I tried with CSS based solution.

```
{
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
width:90%;
}
or 
{
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
width:200px;    //somewhere suggested to use with in px rather than %(just tried)
}
```

But it is not working properly. Then after googling I come to know that text-overflow CSS actually not work well in android phones.

2- I have tried with window.devicePixelRatio and screen.availWidth two methods. But  "screen.availWidth"  do not give proper screen size in Nexus4.

```
var device_width = screen.availWidth;
var device_density = window.devicePixelRatio;
```

3- I have created my own algorithm of trimming title. Which also not work on some devices like micromex and samsung GT-S6802.I am using ow/dd and oh/dd where ow = original_width , oh= original_height and dd= device_density.

I think that there is some difference between physical device pixel and programming pixel(may be a wrong term).I could not use mobile_js as it is not production ready.Still I will try to explore it too to find out some solution.

But if anyone have faced such problem of truncating the text according to device with ( say 90% of device with) then please let me know.It will be of great help.

Although currently I am looking for solution for android devices only but it will be great if the solution can work on ios too.

Comment: Never, ever, use px with Android.  Everything from about 120 pixels up to 2560.

Comment: Can you describe "doesn't work"?  Does it ignore the property (due to lack of support for the text-overflow) or crash and burn horribly?  There's pretty much nothing you can do if Android doesn't support the text-overflow property.

Comment: I have use no-wrap also. It does not trim and obviously never add any ellipse (...). Yes CSS text-overflow is not supported by android. Hence I have tried js solutions as mentioned above.I am looking for solution in javascript/jquery or if possible in CSS.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't because of the [text-rendering property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11860438/text-overflow-ellipsis-jumps-behind-text-on-android)?

Comment: yes I am sure it is not because of text-rendering.. i gone through this too. I am not using text-rendering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed this problem.Hence answering my own problem.

The solution is pretty simple. Here my main concern to get exact device width for different orientations. Below logic works perfectly.

```
var deviceWidth = screen.availWidth;
var deviceHeight = screen.availHeight;
var device_density = window.devicePixelRatio;
switch(window.orientation) {
       case 90: case -90:   //landscape mode
           device_cur_width= (deviceWidth>deviceHeight)?deviceWidth:deviceHeight;
           break;
       default:             //portrait mode
           device_cur_width= ((deviceWidth<deviceHeight)?deviceWidth:deviceHeight);
           break;
}
//I know the exact device width so I can calculate max_allowed_title_width.
max_allowed_title_width = (device_cur_width/device_density) *0.90;
```

Answer (score 0):

this is your actual code = "width **=** 200px;"
You should declare a width % : 
Ej :

css:

```
{
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
width:90%
}
```

It should works fine.
also you should add a nowrap property to prevent the break line. 
css:

```
{
white-space: nowrap;
}
```

also be careful, you mentioned you used "=" instead of ":"

if all that don't work you can too use it javascript :

```
var title = document.getElementById("id of title element");
title.innerHTML = title.innerHTML + "...";
```

So , you should use :

```
var title = document.getElementById("your title element id");
var sW = screen.width;
if (title.offsetWidth <= (sW * 0.9)) {
title.innerHTML = title.innerHTML + "...";
}
)
```

Comment: I tried it .. It is not working properly in nexus 4 and may devices even. Please google text-overflow problem with android.You will get many articles as I have alredy mentioned in request.Also I have already commented there that i have used 'px' on someone suggestion on some portal.Please read the request carefully.

Comment: you try to use ":" instead of "=" xD, if you have a link i can check it for you .

Comment: Ya.. sorry i have corrected it.It was just typo.I have used ":" only.I don't have any link but I have invested almost 2 day, CSS text-overflow not work properly. It work great in browser but not in android app.

Comment: check the js solution dude!.

Comment: "screen.width;" do not provide proper width for some mobiles.Also please refer  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5456582/screen-width-and-screen-availwidth-difference-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can emulate overflow-ellipsis using pseudo elements if you need to.  Note that this will only work if you have a solid background.

http://cssdeck.com/labs/aramol9m

```
<p class="foo">I pity the foo who crosses Mr. T</p>

.foo {
  width: 10em;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: relative;
}

.foo:after {
  display: inline-block;
  content: '...';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: white;
}
```